# A less sexist alternative to 'mansplain'?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, gender-neutral, gender-politics

Mansplain is an interesting term that has been added recently to the Oxford, Merriam-Webster, and Cambridge dictionaries.

Here is the definition as per Oxford.

> (of a man) explain (something) to someone, typically a woman, in a
>   manner regarded as condescending or patronizing.

I ask for an alternative as this act/practice is fairly common and happens regardless of gender at the giving as well as the receiving end.

Comment: Basically, you seem to want terms for the idiom "talk down to".

Comment: Correct! I ask for a single word that would express this. Right now, the closest thing would be mansplain which has rather concerning undertones of gender animosity/strife.

Comment: What's wrong with condescending or patronizing?

Comment: The whole point of the term is to express gender animosity/strife. It's empty without that. You could always invent a gender neutral term e.g. "spousesplain"

Comment: "The whole point of the term is to express gender animosity/strife." That is the very reason I ask for a less pernicious synonym. I hope you get the point of my question now.

Comment: @tr_quest so are you looking for something that has the gender relation or not? If not, why don't the suggested **talk down to**, **condescending** and **patronising** fit?

Comment: Patronizing is a very good word... and really can be use broadly whenever someone explains something they should know you know.  Although, sometimes I've heard 'mansplain' used in a way that means "any analysis of why something isn't as bad as it sounds made in the context of a wrongdoing is wrong" ?

Comment: Any explanation of factors that led to mistakes related to a wrong doing seems to be regarded as "condoning" the behavior since about 2014 ...

Comment: Patronize is good – yet it is not gender-neutral.

Comment: There is also the genusist alternative, **hominidsplain**.

Answer (score 5):

I believe **[condescend](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/condescend)** a gender-neutral way to substitute mansplain; I think it is also a much more appropriate and professional word, and far less loaded. (While modern writers and speakers use condescend primarily as an adjective, it is more versatile than that!)

> > "You see, Terry," condescended Pat, "it's really just basic math – you know, like one plus one equals two?"